# How to combine Spatialite Databases

Tags: database, spatialite, windows

I'm trying to combine a few Spatialite Databases into a single database, so that I can properly reference them, etc. I don't care about referencing them to one another (No foreign keys, etc), but I would like to get them all into a single database. Any suggestions on how I might accomplish this?

As an example, say I'm trying to combine the key tables from this [spatialite database](http://geocommons.com/overlays/33578) with the ones [here](http://geocommons.com/overlays/122736). I want to ensure that the geometry information is copied.

I'm running on Windows 7, and would prefer to not use a different OS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're familiar with SQL, probably the easiest way is to use the capabilities of the underlying SQLite database to "mount" one database onto another (or perhaps both source databases onto a new target database. The SQLite SQL command for this is [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

Conceptually, you'd then SELECT / UPDATE from the source database table(s) into the target table. The exact approach will depend on exactly what you want from the results.

I would caution you that the databases on GeoCommons aren't (or at least, weren't last time I checked) "real" SpatiaLite databases (more like SQLite + FDO), so I'd try to bring in the data via Extended Well Known Binary (EWKB) or similar rather than just copying the blobs across.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is EWKB?

Comment: Expanded that acronym - its a format originally from PostGis (I believe), that is like Well Known Binary (WKB), but includes the SRID.